# How to Refresh WPF Listview correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, listview

I have a class which does some stuff in a simple `foreach` loop.
For each iteration I add an item to a WPF `listview`.

My problem is that values in the `listview` are only visible when the `Foreach` loop is finished.

How can i force a refresh on the UI ? Do i have to use a background worker?

Basically my code is like this :

```
foreach ( xxx in yyy )
{
    Listview.items.add("bla bla bla"):
    ; some stuff
    ; some stuff
}
```

For information, the "stuff" is not long and i think i don't need an async programming....just a way to refresh...

---

Now i'm tring to populate an ObservableCollection then bind it to the listview in order to solve the refresh issu :

```
public static void myClass()
{

    public static ObservableCollection<String> names = new ObservableCollection<String>(); 

    public static void DoMyStuff()
    {

        names.Add("---- Stuff begin at : " + DateTime.Now + " ---" + Environment.NewLine);

        var Sources_URL = myDb.url_source;
        foreach (var url in Sources_URL)
        {
            names.Add("------- Do stuff for : " + url.url_root);
            // Some Stuff
        }
    }

}
```

And here is the xaml :

```
 <ListView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Margin="10,10,10,10" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Name="LstViewMain" ItemsSource="{Binding Names}" />
```

With this, problem is the same, i have to wait the end of the DoMyStuff() function to see the Listview content.

Comment: I think the missing link is where is the call to "DoMyStuff"?

Comment: The call is in the MainWindow.xaml.cs, behind a button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved ! Very simple, i used this and all is ok :)

```
Public Void UpdateUI()
 {
     //Here update your label, button or any string related object.

     //Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new ThreadStart(delegate { }));    
     Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new ThreadStart(delegate { }));
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason that the UI is not updated is that your foreach loop probably runs on the UI thread, hence blocking the UI thread until the operation completes. This is also the reason for the async programming suggestions...
To refresh the UI you need to use the `Dispatcher` of your `UIElement` (See [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/878ea631-c76e-49e8-9e25-81e76a3c4fe3/refresh-the-gui-in-a-wpf-application?forum=wpf)):

```
 foreach (var url in Sources_URL)
 {
     names.Add("------- Do stuff for : " + url.url_root);
     // Some Stuff
     myListView.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, EmptyDelegate)
 }

private static Action EmptyDelegate = delegate() { };
```

Comment: I just tried to add values in an observablecollection and bind the collection to the control in the xaml and it's the same refresh is at end. I will edit my code now.

Comment: ObservableCollection doesn't help, just creates the same problem; you are running your loop on the UI thread.

Comment: But i was doing this in WinForms whitout refresh problem if i'm not wrong. Is it different in WPF ?

Comment: I've tested it on sample (hopefully similar to yours) and it works with the dispatcher. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Hello @AmittaiShapira, The Dispatcher has to be invoked after each 'name.Add' ? Because i have lot of names.add in my code because i have a lot of sutff...I tried and i don't know why but i have only the two first lines visible in the listview...after that i have to wait the end of the stuff to have a refresh..even with the dispatcher.

Comment: Yes - if you want the UI to be refreshed before your method (as I understand ButtonClick) returns, you'll have to use the dispatcher. As I've mentioned, from test application I've created the Dispatcher fixes the refresh issue. You may have other issues (e.g. ListView may need to be resized or scrolled), but if the Dispatcher fixes your refresh issue - please mark this question answered, and ask new one...

Comment: @AmittaiShapira It's very strange because it only refresh two lines.... :( ( My size is OK, and i don't have to scroll...but i don't understand why it refresh only the two first line...In debug mode i see it add 3rd line, then others lines but i only see  the 2 first lines.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to force an update inside of a foreach loop. You should learn to use the async programming style of C#.

Maybe something like this.

```
private async void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        foreach (var item in new string[] { "asd", "asdfasdf", "asd", "asdfasdf", "asd", "asdfasdf", "asd", "asdfasdf" })
        {
            //You have to invoke this on the dispatcher, because you are on a different thread right now.
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => listbox.Items.Add(item));
            await Task.Delay(1000).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Comment: Wow i'm not familliar with this syntax. I don't understand why i need to use asyn programming since my "do stuff" is not long to execute....I just a need to force a refresh.

Comment: The issue is that a refresh cannot happening while your code is using the thread it needs. What async/await does in these instances is give the window a chance to run the refresh by being (at the task system's discretion) either run in the gaps when the UI isn't, or spun off to a different thread (which is why you need to use dispatcher.invoke).

Comment: OK, but the problem is i add new items in the listview in 7 parts of the "do stuff". It's in order to "track" the stuff...Maybe i should use the binding ?

Comment: Binding won't help either. Could you share your 7 part code?

Answer (score -2):

You could open threads to do your stuff, so that the for each loop can finish faster.

```
foreach ( xxx in yyy )
{
    Listview.items.add("bla bla bla");
    Task t = Task.Run(() =>         
    {
      ; some stuff
      ; some stuff
    });
}
```